# Access class constant and static method from string

Tags: php, string, class, methods, static

I have a string containing the class name and I wish to get a constant and call a (static) method from that class.

```
<?php
$myclass = 'b'; // My class I wish to use

$x = new x($myclass); // Create an instance of x
$response = $x->runMethod(); // Call "runMethod" which calls my desired method

// This is my class I use to access the other classes
class x {
    private $myclass = NULL;

    public function __construct ( $myclass ) {
        if(is_string($myclass)) {
            // Assuming the input has a valid class name
            $this->myclass = $myclass;
        }
    }

    public function runMethod() {
        // Get the selected constant here
        print $this->myclass::CONSTANT;

        // Call the selected method here
        return $this->myclass::method('input string');
    }
}


// These are my class(es) I want to access
abstract class a {
    const CONSTANT = 'this is my constant';

    public static function method ( $str ) {
        return $str;
    }
}

class b extends a {
    const CONSTANT = 'this is my new constant';

    public static function method ( $str ) {
        return 'this is my method, and this is my string: '. $str;
    }
}
?>
```

As I expected (more or less), using `$variable::CONSTANT` or `$variable::method();` doesn't work.

Before asking what I have tried; I've tried so many things I basically forgot.

What's the best approach to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To access the constant, use [`constant()`](http://php.net/constant):

```
constant( $this->myClass.'::CONSTANT' );
```

**Be advised**: If you are working with namespaces, you need to specifically add your namespace to the string even if you call `constant()` from the same namespace!

For the call, you'll have to use [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/call_user_func):

```
call_user_func( array( $this->myclass, 'method' ) );
```

**However:** this is all not very efficient, so you might want to take another look at your object hierarchy design. There might be a better way to achieve the desired result, using inheritance etc.

Comment: What about `self::CONSTANT`?

Answer (score 3):

in php 7 you can use this code

```
echo 'my class name'::$b;
```

or

```php
#Uncomment this lines if you're the input($className and $constName) is safe.
$reg = '/^[a-zA-Z_\x80-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x80-\xff]*$/';
if(preg_match($reg,$className) !== 1 || preg_match($reg,$constName) !== 1)
    throw new \Exception('Oh, is it an attack?');
$value = eval("return $className::$constName;");
```

Comment: While this answer may solve the OP's issue, it is recommended that you provide a clear explanation as to how this achieves the solution. Simply posting code-only answers can be unhelpful to the OP and future users. Please elaborate.

Comment: solution is clear ! because title of question is **Access class constant and static method from string**

Comment: This didn't work for me, am using 7.4.21. edit: I'm using `return` instead of `echo`.

Comment: @FabianoLothor please see http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fe133798de43079344f2b8c93c69ea8e30d477e4

Comment: @ThinkBig thanks man, please, look what I mean: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/db1717fb9c5754ca6b919bad9dd862a997444784

Comment: @FabianoLothor I can not find any real solution. but you can use this way http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/46f17bf68e855e5fc68a64678605b3d6396de62b or Reflection in php

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by setting a temporary variable. Not the most elegant way but it works.

```
public function runMethod() {
    // Temporary variable
    $myclass = $this->myclass;
    // Get the selected constant here
    print $myclass::CONSTANT;

    // Call the selected method here
    return $myclass::method('input string');
}
```

I guess it's to do with the ambiguity of the `::`, at least that what the error message is hinting at (`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM`)

Comment: I just wanted to write the exact same answer. This would be the most "sane" version, I think. Although a complete rewrite with inheritance would be much better.

Answer (score 2):

Use `call_user_func` to call static method:

```
call_user_func(array($className, $methodName), $parameter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Classes defined as abstract may not be instantiated, and any class that contains at least one abstract method must also be abstract. Methods defined as abstract simply declare the method's signature - they cannot define the implementation.

When inheriting from an abstract class, all methods marked abstract in the parent's class declaration must be defined by the child; additionally, these methods must be defined with the same (or a less restricted) visibility. For example, if the abstract method is defined as protected, the function implementation must be defined as either protected or public, but not private. Furthermore the signatures of the methods must match, i.e. the type hints and the number of required arguments must be the same. This also applies to constructors as of PHP 5.4. Before 5.4 constructor signatures could differ.
Refer to http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

Answer (score 1):

This might just be tangential to the subject but, while searching for my own issue I found that the accepted answer pointed me in the right direction, so I wanted to share my problem & solution in case someone else might be stuck in a similar fashion.

I was using the PDO class and was building some error options from an ini config file. I needed them in an associative array in the form: `PDO::OPTION_KEY => PDO::OPTION_VALUE`, but it was of course failing because I was trying to build the array with just `PDO::$key => PDO::$value`.

The solution (inspired from the accepted answer):

```
$config['options'] += [constant('PDO::'.$key) => constant('PDO::'.$option)];
```

where everything works if you concatenate the class name and the [Scope Resolution Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) as a string with the variable and get the constant value of the resulting string through the constant function (more [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php)).
Thank you and I hope this helps someone else!